# Nesting a itemized style easylist within a enumerate style one

Tags: easylist

I need to have a list like this:

1. Do action 1
2. Choose between those two options:

   - either do A
   - or do B
3. Do action 3

In LaTeX, I have

```
\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
\ListProperties(Hang=true, Margin=4em)
@ Do action 1
@ Choose between those two options:
    \begin{easylist}[itemize]
    \ListProperties(Hang=true, Margin=6em)
    @ either do A
    @ or do B
    \end{easylist}
\ListProperties(Margin=4em)
@ Do action 3
\end{easylist}
```

The problem with this code is, after the bullet points, the subsequent list items (e.g., action 3) become bullet points. How do I resume the numbering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
\ListProperties(Hang=true, Margin=4em)
@ Do action 1
@ Choose between those two options:
    \begin{easylist}[itemize]
    \ListProperties(Hang=true, Margin=6em)
    @ either do A
    @ or do B
    \end{easylist}
\NewList(Start1=3,Margin=4em)
@ Do action 3
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

As described in the `easylist` [package documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/easylist/easylist-doc.pdf),

> `ListProperties` affects all
>   subsequent items and all subsequent lists, wherever it is issued. If you want to set the parameters back to default, use `\NewList`, which can also have an argument (between parentheses like `\ListProperties`) and
>   will then function as `\ListProperties` if you want to specify again a parameter.

So, that was the trick. Still, there is a misalignment problem between the third item and the first two (first Do is not perfectly aligned to second Do).

So, I suggest another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
\ListProperties(Hang=true, Margin=4em)
@ Do action 1
@ Choose between those two options:
\end{easylist}
    \begin{easylist}[itemize]
    \ListProperties(Hang=true, Margin=6em)
    @ either do A
    @ or do B
    \end{easylist}
\begin{easylist}[enumerate]
\ListProperties(Start1=3,Hang=true, Margin=4em)
@ Do action 3
@ Do action 1
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]